# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: get only the parent

Tags: php, jquery, domparser

im useing "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" for this HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-test-header" class="nav-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="">Test</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="">sub test</a>
                <a href="">sub test</a>
                <a href="">sub test</a>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Test</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="">sub test</a>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get in the end of the result only the parent *"li a"* without the "sub-menu" part.
Its mean, in the end result should be only "Test" not "sub test".
What should be the selector?

PHP code:

```
foreach($html->find(".header-main .nav-menu li > a") as $menu) {
    echo $menu->plaintext;
}
```

Thank you all, And sorry for my bad English :-)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not works for me

Comment: It exists, Maybe the problem is that "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser"  Not support the > selector?

Comment: Ah, you're right! Ghost's answer's second part is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could point out the first `<li>` children from the main `<ul>` first, and from there, target each `<a>` as `->children(0)`.

```
foreach($html->find('ul#menu-test-header', 0)->children() as $li) {
    echo $li->children(0);
}
```

Sidenote: But I'd really suggest `DOMDocument` + `DOMXpath` over `simple-html-dom`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$first_list_links = $xpath->evaluate('//ul[@id="menu-test-header"]/li/a');
foreach($first_list_links as $links) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($links);
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vuIyCq)

Comment: A great idea! But the html sometimes may be slightly different. So I'm a little afraid to use this solution.